# Is there a way of rearranging the order of x-axis of bar plot with two geom_bars on same plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, dplyr

I am trying to rearrange the order of my x axis from the R default into a custom order.
I have tried using the following script however this produces an error
Error: Mapping should be created with `aes()` or `aes_()`.
Any clue on how to get this to work, it has worked in previous graphs with only one geom_bar.

```
Growth4 %>%
  arrange(Label) %>%
  mutate(Label = factor(Label, levels=c( "Control", "B1 <2mm 5%", "B1 <2mm 10%", 
            "B1 <2mm 20%", "B1 >2mm 5%", "B1 >2mm 10%", 
            "B1 >2mm 20%", "B2 <2mm 5%", "B2 <2mm 10%","B2 <2mm 20%", "B2 >2mm 5%", "B2 >2mm 10%", "B2 >2mm 20%", "B3 <2mm 5%", "B3 <2mm 10%", "B3 <2mm 20%", "B3 >2mm 5%", "B3 >2mm 10% ", "B3 >2mm 20%"))) %>%
ggplot(Growth4, aes(x=Label))+
geom_bar(aes(x=Label, y=Shoot.dry.weight ), color="black", fill = "grey42", stat="identity")+
geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Shoot.dry.weight-s.e.shoot, ymax=Shoot.dry.weight+s.e.shoot), width=.2, position=position_dodge(.9)) +
geom_bar(aes(x=Label, y=-Root.Dry.weight),color="black", fill = "grey60", stat="identity")+
geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=-Root.Dry.weight-s.e.root, ymax=-Root.Dry.weight+s.e.root), width=.2, position=position_dodge(.9)) +
theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90, size=12, color="black"),panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),panel.background = element_blank(),axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),axis.text.y=element_text( size=14, color="black"),axis.title=element_text(size=14, face="bold"))+
ylab("Root dry weight(g)                Shoot dry weight(g)")+
xlab("Treatment")+
ylim(-3,6)
```

Comment: Try with `ggplot(aes(x=Label))`, i.e. without the additional `Growth4`. As you pipe your dataset into the ggplot call, adding another dataset will raise an error as it will be assigned to the mapping arguemnt.

Comment: Tried that it produces the following error, Warning messages:
1: Removed 18 rows containing missing values (geom_bar). 
2: Removed 18 rows containing missing values (geom_bar). Creating a chart with only one bar and 19 error bars

Comment: Never mind the labels and the reordered labels werent matching. Fixing now

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.